# Apply MasterPage to even pages in QuarkXpress

Tags: print-design, page-layout, quarkxpress

I have created a new project with automatic text box (non facing pages) and have created a second master page that I would now like to apply to all even pages.

InDesign has this option when I right-click on a master page, but I can't seem to find it anywhere in QuarkXpress 9.1. Google hasn't been nice to me either.

**Can anyone point me in the right direction? Even to say "it can't be done"**.

Comment: Easy in Indesign. Right-click/Control-Click the master page and choose Apply Master Page to.... Sorry, haven't touched Xpress in years. I added a small bounty to see if an Xpress user will explain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have version 9 of Quark. However, I believe you can accomplish what you're looking for by dragging the master page icon on top of any page you'd like to have follow your new master.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm with Scott in my QXP rustiness. But I used to be a master ...

In the old days (QXP4), you could select the pages in the palette then option-click the appropriate master. That should apply it immediately.